# Python Django LineBot Error 54 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-requests

I'm trying to crete linebot through python Django, I want to send some messages and let it scrape the website. Since there is form on the website, I use post request to send the form.
Although I scrape the data successfully, there is error message showed in the python. It seems linebot occupy post method in Django and I send another post request again. I'm not sure my understanding is correct. I can't find any solution about this. Could someone teach me how to fix it?

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50246)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Below is my code, I receive some keyword and post request to website. Finally, reply to user

```
@csrf_exempt
def callback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signature = request.META['HTTP_X_LINE_SIGNATURE']
        body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        
        content = "None"
        try:
            events = parser.parse(body, signature)
        except InvalidSignatureError:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        except LineBotApiError:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        for event in events:
            if isinstance(event, MessageEvent):
                msg = event.message.text.strip()
                if msg.startswith('!'):
                    msg = msg.replace('!', '')
                    if msg == 'temp':
                        content = "HELP"
                    elif msg.startswith(' '):
                        content = 'Command not found'
                    elif ' ' in msg:
                        info = msg.split(' ')
                        if len(info) > 2:
                            content = 'Too many arguments'
                        else:
                            ID = info[1]
                            temp = temperature.TempReport(ID)
                            content = temp.scrape()
                            #content = 'Test'
                    else:
                        content = 'Unknown command'

                    line_bot_api.reply_message(
                            event.reply_token,
                            TextSendMessage(text=content)
                            )
                    print('submit success')
                else:
                    line_bot_api.reply_message(
                            event.reply_token,
                            TextSendMessage(text=msg)
                            )
        return HttpResponse()
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Here is scrape code

```
def scrape(self):
    if not self.postToServer():
        return f'ID:{self.ID} submit temperature fail!' 
    return f'ID:{self.ID} submit temperature successfully
```

```
def postToServer(self):
    self.session.post(self.url_in, data=self.payload)
    sleep(0.1)
    resp = self.session.get(self.url_out)
    sleep(0.1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, features='lxml')
    result = soup.find(class_='title-text').text.strip()
    return 0 if not 'completed' in result else
```

The post request work fine and the error happened when I return HttpResponse in callback function. I don't know what is the issue here...

Comment: `connection reset by peer` is telling you that the other machine has disconnected without a reply.  While this could be due to your code, nobody can answer that without you posting code that reproduces this problem.  Please update your question with some code.

Comment: @PoDuck Sorry for late reply. I update my code in details. Do you know where is the problem..Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with linebot, or line for that matter, but I can pretty much guarantee that it's the lines that speak to the line platform that start with `line_bot_api.reply_message` are your problem.  Find out if your `event.reply_token` and `content` are what you expect them to be before they are sent in the reply.  It could be that if it is malformed that the server will just drop the connection.  Print them out before they are sent to figure out the contents of those variables.  At least now there is code that someone who is more familiar might be able to help with.

Comment: @PoDuck I may find the issue that I need to response server within 1s in Linebot but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any ideal how to reply server first then handle the event? I'm still try to find a way out of this. Thanks

Comment: My comment was because I was doing post reviews.  I know that without decent information in the qeustion, many questions go unanswered, so I was trying to help you make your question better.  I am not familiar with what you are working on though, unfortunately.  You may try offering a bounty on this question.  That will get more attention, and often gets you more professional help.